# SailsJs Sockets (Node) gives 404 Error during WebSocket handshake, when used with ssl configuration with nginx Proxy

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, socket.io, sails.js

SailsJs Sockets  (Node) gives 404 Error during WebSocket handshake, when used with ssl configuration with nginx as Reverse Proxy. But when I use remove just ssl configuration from my Nginx it is working fine.

Detailed Error Message:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://desktop.panzuracloud.com/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=1.2.1&__sails_io_sdk_platform=node&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Here is my Nginx conf file:

```
upstream panzura_server_upstream {
  server 127.0.0.1:1337;
}

server {
# The IP that you forwarded in your router (nginx proxy)
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/panzura/certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/panzura/private.key;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name desktop.panzuracloud.com;


  location / {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass http://panzura_server_upstream;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection &quot;upgrade&quot;;
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

On Frontend I am using react and have a fairly simple code:

```
import React from 'react';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import sailsIOClient from "sails.io.js";

class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
    io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false;
    io.sails.url = 'ws://desktop.panzuracloud.com';
    io.socket.on("connect", data => {
      console.log('connect',data);
    });

    io.socket.on("connect_error", data => {
      console.log('connect_error',data);
    });

    io.socket.on("connect_timeout", data => {
      console.log('connect_timeout',data);
    });

    io.socket.on('appMetricUpdate', (body) => {
      console.log(body.data.processes);
    });

  }

  render() { 
    return (<h1>Hi</h1>);
  }

}
```

**Please Note:** This same code is working when I remove ssl configuration from nginx and put the location direcive in server block listening on port 80.

Comment: Change `io.sails.url` to `https://desktop.panzuracloud.com` https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client#?programmatic-configuration-using-iosails

Comment: @nahanil, Thanks I realized the mistake after posting this question and reading sails docs. I have done exactly what you are saying, it is working now.